# Add reusable code to existing protractor page objects file

Tags: javascript, page-objects, protractor

I inherited 45 spec files with correlating page object files that are used only to locate elements on the pages. I am trying to create reusable code, is it best practice/can additional exports be added to the same page object file or do they need to exist in a separate 'helper' file?

Article for reference: [How to reuse code in Protractor / AngularJS Testing](http://corpus.hubwiz.com/2/angularjs/24782783.html).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The idea is to *keep the Page Object abstraction layer as clean and modular as possible* avoiding inter-spaghetti-connected page objects with each other.

If you need to use a helper module or function inside a page object, that's fine. If you need to import the nested page objects into the parent page object - this is also perfectly fine, as long as the nestedness follows your page object design and is logical.

For instance, for complicated screens we have this nested page object structure:

```
- po
  - parent.po
    - child1.po.js
    - child2.po.js
    - index.js
```

And, then, inside the `index.js` we may have something like:

```
var Child1Page = require("./child1.po"),
    Child2Page = require("./child2.po");

var ParentPage = function () {
    this.url = "/#/parent";

    this.someField = $("#myid");

    // child page objects
    this.child1 = new Child1Page(this);
    this.child2 = new Child2Page(this);
};

module.exports = new ParentPage();
```

which allows us to access the child page objects from the parent page object with the dot-notation.